# How to repair this torn gutter?

Tags: gutters

I recently had a large truck back into the aluminum gutter on my garage and tear it open. What is the easiest way to repair this damage, please?

Replacing the whole gutter seems like overkill, but maybe attempting a patch is not feasible?

[image]
[image]

Comment: You did not tell us what material the gutter is made of.  Looks like aluminum but just want to be sure.

Comment: It depends where you are and what you consider overkill... It looks like a k gutter, which is is usually about $2.30 a foot.

Comment: How much is aesthetics an issue to you? It can be repaired in place. How to repair it in place and have it look good (enough), that is the real question

Comment: @Alaska Man sorry! Yes, it is Aluminum.

Comment: The "easiest method" is to get the truck company's insurance company to fix it professionally, as they are obligated to do, since the truck damaged it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used Bondo from 3M for gutter repairs. It's a two part fiberglass filler that will bond well with aluminum and plastics. It sets quickly and can be sanded in a few hours.
Just bend the aluminum back in place to support the Bondo. You mght want to use some duct tape on the inside of the gutter to hold it together. I would do the inside first and let it dry to give it structure and then do the outside.
Sand and paint.
[image]

Comment: Sounds like another good option. I like the reinforcing tape bit to make sure any adhesive does not crack.

Answer (score 2):

From the tear it looks like aluminum. I'd bend all the pieces back into the original shape and then fill in the cracks and skim coat the area with some J B Weld. This stuff works great. It can be sanded to smooth it out and then painted to match your gutter and is completely resistant to water.

[image]

Comment: I had no idea adhesives were an option here. I thought I was stuck trying to rivet in some kind of patch piece. If the epoxy will hold (not sure how it likes Canadian winters?) then this might be worth a try.